# Trouble Querying with RecordId in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

For my first real attempt at a lightning component, I am trying to make a related list that can be modified by different filters based on what you would like to see. I have it mostly working as intented, but I cannot seem to correctly query for related records, and am stuck either getting all of the records that meet my filter, or none.

I am attempting to use force:hasRecordId, which seems like it would make things quite simple, but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly even with the lightning component itself, as I try to display the recordId and get a blank component.

Code is below, any help is appreciated.

Component
`

```
<lightning:card iconName="custom:custom84" title="Open Backlog Items" class="slds-is-relative">
    <div class="slds-p-left_medium slds-p-right_medium">
        <ul class="slds-list_vertical slds-has-dividers_top-space">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.openBacklogItems.length &gt; 0}">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.openBacklogItems}" var="item">
                    <li class="slds-list__item">
                      <a href="{!'/lightning/r/BackLogItem__c/'+ item.Id + '/view'}" target="_blank">{! item.Name }</a>
                        <br></br>
                      Status :
                       {!item.Status__c}
                        <br></br>
                      <ui:outputRichText aura:id = 'desc' value = '{!item.Description__c}'/>
                    </li>
                </aura:iteration>
                <aura:set attribute="else">
                    <li class="slds-list__item">
                        <h3 class="slds-text-medium">{!recordID}</h3>

                    </li>
                </aura:set>
            </aura:if>
        </ul>
    </div>
</lightning:card>
```

`

JS Controller

```
({
    getOpenBacklogItems : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getRelatedBacklogItems");
        action.setParams({
            recordID : component.get("v.recordID")
        })
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var relatedIssues = response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.openBacklogItems", relatedIssues);
        });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Apex Controller

```
public with sharing class RelatedBacklogItemsController {

   @AuraEnabled
    public static List<BacklogItem__c> getRelatedBacklogItems(ID recordID){
        //TODO: Figure out how to filter by application record page being viewed
        return [SELECT Id, Name, Description__c, Level_of_Effort__c, Piority__c, Status__c FROM BacklogItem__c WHERE Status__c != 'Completed' AND Status__c != 'Rejected' AND Application__c = :recordID ORDER BY Status__c];
    }
}
```

I would think that this should query by application based on the record page we are looking at, but the query always returns nothing, and when I attempt to display recordId on the component using {!recordId} I am left with a blank component. I am guessing I am missing something quite simple, but have not been able to figure it out to this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case Sensitivity: `recordId` and not `recordID`.

Pay attention to the value provider: `{!v.XXX}`

```
<li class="slds-list__item">
     <h3 class="slds-text-medium">{!v.recordId}</h3>
</li>
```

Also,

```
component.get("v.recordId")
```

Comment: I knew it would be something small I was overlooking like that, thank you for the second set of eyes. Saved me a lot of time pounding my head against the wall for an easy fix.

Comment: Happy to help :-)